# Yolov7 Weights Trained in Remote Server works there only

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo, inference, yolov7

Weights in the server work in server only, when i download the weights and run it in my local pc then im noticing that it doesnt detect any object at all.

Commands used
python train.py --epochs 10 --cache-images --exist-ok --adam --device 0,1,2

python detect.py --source data/pothole_split/train/potholes0_png_jpg.rf.3e90971629af3f862c24298d8a1b5069.jpg --weights weights/best_10.pt

I have added default arguments for the data, cfg and other parameters.

Tried in Server, detection works  -- linux
Tried in local machine, detection didnt work  -- windows

Answer (score 1):

It seems there was some package error in the conda env in my local pc, deleting the env and reinstalling the packages fixed the problem.